# How to autoplay audio on iPhone using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to make the audio to play when the page is loaded.
It is working well on PC and Android but not working on iPhone.

I know that Autoplay is forbidden on iPhone.
Are there any way to achieve this function on iPhone?

Comment: Perhaps this belongs at some black hat hacking site?  You are asking for an exploit, that Apple will hopefully fix before it does you any good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that Autoplay is forbidden on iPhone.

Correct.  Audio autoplay will not work on iPhone, nor most other browsers on most platforms.

> Are there any way to achieve this function on iPhone?

Not from a webpage, there isn't.

Comment: But I saw a project that the function is working well.

Comment: @AleksandrAsanov Prove it.  And, add those details to your question.